# I want to detect a fast moving ball in a video using opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, tracking

I want to detect a fast moving ball in a video; I have tried using background subtraction. I can see the ball motion but I can't detect it as I have some other object moving (the spinning part on the middle) and they are so close!!

How I can ignore those objects, and focus just in the ball while moving.

[here is the original video for the moving ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfwNgcScEKs)

And a screenshot for the output video after background subtraction

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If your environment is stationary you could probably just mask out the bit that's causing interference. I'm sure OpenCV supports something like that. I'd also get a camera with a slower shutter/better frame rate...

Comment: please can you tell me how to make out the bit causing interference?? also the camera position could change!!

Comment: One way could be to require the user to take a bit of footage of just the wheel spinning to map our the area with interference, and create a mask based on just that.

Comment: first optimize your imaging setup. viewing angle, illumination, frame rate, focus... what is your goal? what do you mean with "detect"? do you want to track it and predict its movement? measure its speed or what?

Comment: @Piglet i want to know when it's moving or not ??

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Virkkunen  please can you explain more

Comment: @lafiraed: If you have the user take some video of just the wheel spinning you can detect motion in that video to figure out where the area that has movement without the ball is. Then create a mask out of that area after some processing (remove small artifacts, round up a bit) and ignore motion in that area when looking for the ball. It's not perfect but should help. I'm not going to write any code for you because I haven't used OpenCV myself.

Comment: "the camera position can change" - how much and how often? can we assume that the camera is stationary for multiple games? Or is the camera handheld and isnt any stationary over more than a few frames? Please explain more detailed, those information will have big impact on the chosable methods.

Comment: @Micka i can assume the camera position to be fixed because it can change just between video , so we can consider it static, so we have a static camera and a fast moving ball , how i can just now if the ball is moving or not?